# Oracle trigger on multiple tables

Tags: oracle, plsql

i have 3 tables A,B,C.
I have a stored procedure of these 3 tables with join condition inserted in 4th table D.
now what i want is "ANY INSERT OR UPDATE"made to these 3 tables(A,B,C) should update 4th table D. Can any one please tel how to write trigger in pl/sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need three triggers, that do the required updates on `D`. E.g. for table `A` this might be:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ins_upd_A
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON A 
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  -- required declarations
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN 
    UPDATE D 
       SET column1 = :new.column 
     WHERE column1 = :old.column ...
  END IF;
  IF UPDATING THEN
    -- do required updates on D here 
  END IF;
END;
```

If you have a stored procedure that performs this update you might implement something similar like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_ins_upd_A
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON A 
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  -- required declarations
BEGIN
  IF INSERTING THEN 
    my_procedure_one (...);
  END IF;
  IF UPDATING THEN
    my_procedure_two (...);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why we need to duplicate IF clause as trigger fires on insert or update only?

Comment: Good point - think I created the second example too quickly  ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the query complexity for creating the fourth table's data, this may be better implemented (more robustly, with greater flexibility and less code) with an on-commit fast refresh materialised view.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28326/repmview.htm